# Datasource for kendo treelist having progressbar

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treelist

I'm currently working of kendo treelist which has a progress bar.

**1**) while first binding the progress bar is visible properly and on clicking the drill option for treelist it is no longer visible;
**2**) here is the dogo I have created for reference. Could any help me to catch the issue.

http://dojo.telerik.com/OLiFE/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the solution, Issue was due to the Collapse and expand method were getting trigger very soon, here is the working dogo for other folks to refer,

`http://dojo.telerik.com/OLiFE/18`